# Forwarding submitted text to a function

Tags: php, html

Okay so I have a PHP file and it has a textarea. There is also a button, which when clicked already redirects you to *another page. I've added the textarea above the button and when the button is clicked I would like it to forward the text in the textarea to the *next page (note where the asterisks are).

So far I'm using this in the *other page:

```
$comment = $_POST['comment']; <-- fetches from the page before
$users->updateUser($id, 'appreason', $comment); <-- calls the function
```

The function linked to $users updates my database. It should update the users `comment` column to the text they entered before. The SQL is all fine, as I've used similar codes before.

The issue I'm having is the PHP. The SQL doesn't update and everything else runs as normal. It's as if I never added the code. Any help is appreciated.

```
<div class="panel-body"><div class="form-group"><textarea name="comment"      class="form-control" placeholder="Comment" rows="1"></textarea></div></div>
```

Above is the textarea I'm using. `$_POST['comment']` fetches what's entered there.

The SQL works because I'm using it for other things eg. logging into the site. But anywho, here is the query ran:

```
final public function updateUser($k, $key, $value)  
{       
    global $engine;                 
    $engine->query("UPDATE accounts SET " . $key . " = '" . $engine->secure($value) . "' WHERE id = '" . $k . "' LIMIT 1");
    $_SESSION['user'][$key] = $engine->secure($value);      
}
```

The $engine part definitely works.

Comment: We're going to need to see more code, like the SQL. Also check that `$comment` contains what you think it does.

Comment: I've edited the main post with more code.

Comment: Is `$id` contains valid value?.. I have not noticed issues in your code. I guess, the `$id` value doesn't exists in the database table and query has no effect on your database.

Comment: $id is valid and works with other things: $core->appAction($id, $action); When called, this function works (it modifies a different table in my database).

Comment: I'm try to say by another words :) .. Are you sure you have valid and exists `$id` value exactly at this update? I have another suggestion, it's depends on how many databases you use (sometimes apps use more than one database), maybe you try to update another database (dev/production/test/etc) and check the result inside the different one? Is your database error logger notifies you about successful query-execution?

Comment: $id works because appAction is called at the exact same time and I only use one database

Comment: Is `accounts` table has the row with `id = '$id'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ideas for troubleshooting this:

(1) At top of the `next` page (the PHP page):

```
<?php
    echo 'Received: ' . $_POST['comment'];
    die();
```

Make sure your text is being received in the second file.

(2) Remove previous changes from idea (1) and change as follows:

```
$comment = 'This is a test 9876'; <-- temporary change, just for testing
```

Then manually run the `next.php` (or whatever you called it) file and make sure the string "This is a test 9876" goes into the database.

That will probably expose the problem. But if not, please post additional info here and we'll help you to continue troubleshooting.

By the way - the best way to use StackOverflow is to ask a question, receive responses, choose a "Best" answer, and then ask a new question next time - even if they overlap. This works best because when you ask a new question there are dozens of people who read it and attempt to help, rather than only one or two when you add new information to an existing question.

Comment: Okay so I've tried this and located /where/ the issue is. I set $comment to 'test' and it worked, set it into the database and everything. After changing tiny bits I can confirm the issue is with the textarea & $_POST or something. I set $comment to $_POST['comment'] (which is the textarea box input). When I tested it, it set the cell in the database to absolutely nothing. So it's changing it, but changing it to nothing. Before  I tested it the cell said 'test' but after running it, the cell is '' (aka nothing). This happens even though text is entered into the textarea.

Comment: Continued: So I'm thinking it must be an issue with calling $_POST over two PHP files. The process is: File1.php has the textarea. You click a button and it takes you to File2.php. File2.php fetches $_POST['comment'] from the textarea in File1.php.

Comment: Very likely the problem is that the textarea data either is: (1) not properly captured prior to being AJAXed across to PHP, or (2) not correctly transmitted/received on PHP side. So, on File1.php, when button is clicked, alert (or console.log) the textarea data. Next test: on File2.php, immediately echo back what was received: `<?php // echo $_POST['comment']; // die();` *(the // means press Enter)* and back over on File1.php: `success: function(data){ alert(data); }`