# PHP issue with $_POST and text boxes's in two different files

Tags: php, html, post

In my previous question ([Forwarding submitted text to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37424006/forwarding-submitted-text-to-a-function?noredirect=1#comment62354940_37424006)) I was told to create a new question.

After troubleshooting my issue I found out that the text wasn't carrying over from file1.php to file2.php. Basically, in file1.php I had a textarea. When the user clicks the button, it navigates to file2.php. In file2.php it attempts to fetch the input text from the textarea in file1 using $_POST['comment'] (the name of the textarea is 'comment'). So after troubleshooting I found out $_POST isn't doing it's job and fetching the text from file1.

I use this code: `$comment = $_POST['comment'];`. But after running it, even though I've entered text in the textarea, $comment is nothing. Just nil.

I'm not sure which code is required, but I'll post it upon request.

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment" rows="1"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

^ above is the textarea code.

```
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$users->updateUser($core->getAppInfo($id, "applicant"), 'appreason', $comment);
```

^ when the user clicks the button it goes to page 2, and page 2 uses this.
The second line which is the SQL has been tested and works. I tested it by setting $comment to 'test' and it updated fine.

```
<form action="appaction.php" method="post"><textarea name="comment" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment" rows="1"></textarea></form>
```

^ new form.

```
Notice: Undefined index: comment
```

The line in question:

```
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
```

Comment: You should probably provide the code for both files, but definitely at least `file1.php`

Comment: what does the textarea html look like? Does it have a name="comment"?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to retrieve it from a SELECT in db and trying to echo it back, correct? Kind of hard to tell without seeing the code you're now using. Make sure that you didn't give a `value` for that `<textarea>` neither, because it doesn't have a `value` attribute.

Comment: I think the error is obvious, but we need to see the code **from both scripts** to be sure.

Comment: rsn: Yes - <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment" rows="1"></textarea>

Comment: Please put your code in your question, not in the comments.  And please post your complete code from `file1.php`, not just a snippet.

Comment: Fred: No it's not fetching from the database. I'm trying to set a cell in the database to what the user types in the textarea. The SQL all works, however.

Comment: btw, you didn't post the form tag in your other question, and here neither so we don't know if you are using a POST method. `<form>` defaults to a GET if POST isn't implied.

Comment: Updated with more code. I posted the full line where the textarea is.

Comment: **but you did not yet post your `<form........>` tag**

Comment: @RiggsFolly do you feel "them" coming?....... below - wait for it.

Comment: There is no <form> tag in the code I used

Comment: **KAPOWWWWWWwwwww** No `<form>` tag therefore no form therefore no data sent from the browser to the `page2.php` script. In fact `page2.php` will not even have been run!!!

Comment: I love it when I'm right. hold on, posting an answer for this. Edit: *done'th.*

Comment: @JackAlmighty You should really take a course on basic HTML.

Comment: I am about to tell you a big secret, **keep it to yourself** There is this thing called [the manual, Shhhhhhh](http://php.net/docs.php) and in there is a page called [Dealing with Forms](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly too late, we all seen it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Not many questioners here have as far as I can tell

Comment: $_POST its a supper global with local scope. So if  appaction.php  is not including both file1.php and file2.php depending of its states you will loose $_POST data between redirections.  or  you may store it as session and use on.

Comment: In `file2.php`, or `appaction.php` per your form action, is there any additional code/functionality that might be clearing your `$_POST` data? Your code doesn't look as simple as a basic 2 page form, seeing as you are then dealing with a `$users` object on the receiving end. `$_POST` isn't broken. There is something happening in your code that is causing this. Your best bet is to post the full contents of both files in question, and any logic associated with them that might not be present/obvious.

Answer (score 1):

> *There is no `<form>` tag in the code I used – JackAlmighty*

You stated in comments you weren't using a form.

You need to use one and to use a post method.

That is why your POST array never gets populated.

I.e.

```
<form action="handler.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment" rows="1"></textarea>
...
</form>
```

FYI: If there's no method in `<form>` then that is equivalent to a GET.

I.e.: `<form action="handler.php" method="get">`

Sidenote: If you want to populate it, you can simply put a variable in there.

I.e.:

```
<textarea name="comment" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment" rows="1"><?php echo $var; ?></textarea>
```

or add an `if(!empty($var)){ echo $var; }` in its place.

---

Check out "Dealing with forms" on PHP.net:

- http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

---

### Edit

**Page 1:** The HTML form.

**Page 2:**

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// or use isset() instead of !empty()
if(!empty($_POST['comment'])){
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];

    $users->updateUser($core->getAppInfo($id, "applicant"), 'appreason', $comment);

}

else{
    echo "Something went haywire.";
}
```

Comment: I've just thoroughly tested it and still, it's not working. The value isn't passed to the next file. I've added the form as instructed (i'll add to main question).

Comment: @JackAlmighty use error reporting then http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and make sure your db code isn't failing neither, so check for errors against that also.

Comment: @JackAlmighty Just a hunch. Change that `<textarea>` to this `<input type="text" name="comment">` and enter just the word `test`. If that works, then something in your `<textarea>` is causing it to fail.

Comment: I'm making it echo the $comment instead at the moment, but it's blank so it's not passing what's entered. I'll try changing <textarea> now, 1 sec.

Comment: @JackAlmighty how are you submitting this? are you not using a submit button? I.e.: `<input type="submit">`. see my other comment just above also. At this point, you need to update your question with the full code and appropriately named as per which file contains what and how. This is getting out of hand.

Comment: Just tried changing textarea to the one you suggested. Still doesn't work.

Comment: @JackAlmighty reload and see my edit near the bottom. I can't do any better than that, sorry. btw, `updateUser` that looks to be  an UPDATE and you may be missing a WHERE clause and is REALLY hard to tell now. make sure you haven't fallen victim to caching neither.

Comment: The updateUser is a function in another php file, works okay as I've tested by setting $comment to just 'test' and it processed fine. I enabled errors and it did print one, I edited the main question and you can see it at the bottom.

Comment: @JackAlmighty use `if(!empty($_POST['comment'])){...]` or instead of `!empty` use `isset()` as outlined in my **Edit.** Again, I can't see this failing. I've done what I could here.

Comment: Done that, so now, it displays 'Something went wrong' as that's what I set it it to say if it's empty. So, it's obvious now the $_POST isn't fetching what's been typed in.

Answer (score 0):

```
    file1.php //code   
  <form action="file2.php" method="post">
   <div class="panel-body">
   <div class="form-group">
    <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment"      rows="1"></textarea>
    </div>
    </div>

  <input type="submit" value="submit">
   </form>

  file2.php
  <?php
   $comment = $_POST['comment'];
   echo $comment;
   ?>
```